# How to change the css class of textarea (textarea used in NicEdit) with using addclass and removeclass methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nicedit

I am validating `textarea` with **NicEdit**.

```
var getContent = nicEditors.findEditor("SubSliderDescription").getContent();

bValid = bValid && checkBlankTextArea(getContent, "SubSliderDescription")

function checkBlankTextArea(o, n) {
    if (o == "<br>" || o == null) {
        //class to be add to textarea to show validations 
        // o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips(n + " is required.");
        return false;
    } else {
        //o.removeClass("ui-state-error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

If validation fails nic Editor should be apply `ui-state-error` class(which shows red border of control) else not.
But it is showing error in script that method addClss or removeClass can not apply.

Any Solution?

Comment: classes are added or removed to HTML elements that have been selected by jquery  e.g. `$("#myId").addClass('myClass')` where myId is the id of an HTML element.

Comment: Try placing `o = $(o);` before your `IF` statement. This will make the element a jQuery element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function checkBlankTextArea(o, n) {
    if ($(o).prop('tagName') == "TEXTAREA") {// check for textarea
        //class to be add to textarea to show validations
        $(o).addClass("ui-state-error");// add class here
        updateTips(n + " is required.");
        return false;
     }
     else {
         //o.removeClass("ui-state-error");
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Trupti use `console.log(o)` in you `function` to check the `elements`.